# How do I stop a key detection script from logging the same key multiple times?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am currently having an issue where I have a key set to start a process, then press another key to go up and down, but if I release the first key, then hit it again, the amount that is scrolled is multiplied (I think). For example, I press 'G' then press 'U' to go up and 'J' to go down. When I am holding down 'G' the first time, it works flawlessly. However, if I release 'G', then press it again to scroll more, when I press 'U' once, it does the input 2 times. If I release and press 'G' once more to scroll, it shows that I press either 'U' or 'J' 3 times. Am I missing something really simple here? Here is the sample code.

```
userInput.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, gameProcessed)
    
    if not gameProcessed then
        
        print("Not game processed!")
        if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.G then 
            
            print("G is Held")
            
            userInput.InputBegan:Connect(function(input2, gP)
                
                local db = false
                
                if not gP then
                    
                    print("Also not game processed!")
                    
                    if input2.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.U and input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.G then
                        
                        print("U was pressed!")
                        
                        if not db then
                            db = true
                            print("db: "..tostring(db))

                            if Multi + 1 > 20 then

                                Multi = 20

                            else

                                Multi = Multi + 1
                                print("Multi: "..Multi)

                            end

                            print("Multi: "..Multi)
                            wait(0.5)
                            db = false
                            print("db: "..tostring(db))
                            
                        end
                        
                    elseif input2.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.J and input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.G then
                        
                        print("J was pressed!")
                        
                        if Multi - 1 < 2 then
                            
                            Multi = 2
                            
                        else
                            
                            Multi = Multi - 1
                            print("Multi: "..Multi)
                            
                        end
                        
                        print("Multi: "..Multi)
                        
                    end
                    
                end
                
            end)
            
        end
        
    end
    
end)
```

EDIT:

I got it to forcibly stop my keyPressed event, sort of, but I'm still having the issue of increasing ticks, which as you said, is due to multiple keyPressed events starting. I have the inputEnded function that sets keysPressed to nil. Here is my updated code:

```
local function onInputBegan(input, gameProcessed)
    
    if gameProcessed then
        return
    end
    
    pressedKeys[input.KeyCode] = true
    
    if pressedKeys[Enum.KeyCode.G] then
        
        gDown = true
        
        if not debounce then

            debounce = true

            if hasPower.Value then

                if powerEquipped.Value == "PowerUp" then
                    
                    while gDown do
                        
                        print("LOOP!")
                        
                        if isPowered.Value == true then
                            
                            gDown = false
                            isPowered.Value = false
                            multi.Value = multi.Value / Multi
                            print("Exited Power!")
                            print("G reset!")
                            break

                        elseif powerStamCost.Value <= stam.Value and stam.Value > powerStamDrain.Value and not isPowered.Value then

                            baseChargeTicks = ((((Multi - 2) * (1 / 6)) + 2) * 4)

                            if chargeTicks >= baseChargeTicks then
                                
                                gDown = false
                                print("In Power")
                                chargeTicks = 0
                                stam.Value = stam.Value - powerStamCost.Value
                                multi.Value = multi.Value * Multi
                                isPowered.Value = true
                                wait(staminaRate)
                                chargeTicks = 0
                                print("G Reset!")
                                break
                                
                            else
                                
                                chargeTicks = chargeTicks + 1
                                wait(increment)                             
                                print("charge: "..chargeTicks.."/"..baseChargeTicks)
                                
                            end
                            
                        end

                    end

                end

            end
            
        end
        
        debounce = false
        
    end
    
    if pressedKeys[Enum.KeyCode.U] then

        if hasPower.Value then

            if powerEquipped.Value == "PowerUp" then

                if Multi + 1 > 20 then

                    Multi = 20

                else

                    Multi = Multi + 1
                    print("Multi: "..Multi)

                end

                chargeTicks = 0

            end

        end

    elseif pressedKeys[Enum.KeyCode.J] then

        if hasPower.Value then

            if powerEquipped.Value == "PowerUp" then

                if Multi - 1 < 2 then

                    Multi = 2

                else

                    Multi = Multi - 1
                    print("Multi: "..Multi)

                end

                chargeTicks = 0

            end

        end

    end
    
end
```

Here is the printed output when attempting to use the keys:

15:30:02.097  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:02.348  charge: 1/8  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:02.348  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:02.363  Multi: 3  -  Client - PowerUp:109
15:30:02.513  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:02.613  charge: 0/8.6666666666667  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:02.614  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:02.646  Multi: 4  -  Client - PowerUp:109
15:30:02.764  charge: 0/8.6666666666667  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:02.764   ▶ LOOP! (x2)  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:02.864  charge: 0/9.3333333333333  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:02.864  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:02.947  Multi: 5  -  Client - PowerUp:109
15:30:03.017  charge: 0/9.3333333333333  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.017  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.031  charge: 1/10  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.031   ▶ LOOP! (x2)  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.130  charge: 3/10  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.130  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.214  Multi: 6  -  Client - PowerUp:109
15:30:03.280  charge: 0/10  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.280  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.297  charge: 1/10.666666666667  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.297  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.331  charge: 2/10.666666666667  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.331   ▶ LOOP! (x2)  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.397  charge: 4/10.666666666667  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.397  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.479  Multi: 7  -  Client - PowerUp:109
15:30:03.547  charge: 0/10.666666666667  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.548  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.548  charge: 1/11.333333333333  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.548  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.598  charge: 2/11.333333333333  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.598  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.614  charge: 3/11.333333333333  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.614  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.664  charge: 4/11.333333333333  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.664  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.814  charge: 5/11.333333333333  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.814  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.814  charge: 6/11.333333333333  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.814  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.863  charge: 7/11.333333333333  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.864  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.881  charge: 8/11.333333333333  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.881  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:03.914  charge: 9/11.333333333333  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:03.915  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:04.064  charge: 10/11.333333333333  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:04.064  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:04.064  charge: 11/11.333333333333  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:04.064  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:04.114  charge: 12/11.333333333333  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:04.114  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:04.114  In PowerUp  -  Client - PowerUp:64
15:30:04.114  Recalculating Bonus via Multi!  -  Client - PowerDisplayScript:84
15:30:04.114  Recalculating Power via Bonus!  -  Client - PowerDisplayScript:98
15:30:04.130  Health Draining!!  -  Client - HealthBarScript:40
15:30:04.147   ▶ charge: 0/11.333333333333 (x4)  -  Client - PowerUp:78
15:30:05.130  G Reset!  -  Client - PowerUp:71
15:30:05.163   ▶ Health Draining!! (x5)  -  Client - HealthBarScript:40
15:30:09.948  LOOP!  -  Client - PowerUp:46
15:30:09.948  Recalculating Bonus via Multi!  -  Client - PowerDisplayScript:84
15:30:09.949  Recalculating Power via Bonus!  -  Client - PowerDisplayScript:98
15:30:09.949  Exited PowerUp!  -  Client - PowerUp:53
15:30:09.949  G reset!  -  Client - PowerUp:54

Comment: posting the printed output would make your problem description much clearer

Comment: I solved the issue. I simply had to create two key detection functions. I appreciate the help Piglet.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple.

Everytime you press G you connect another event listener to the InputBegan event.

So after having pressed G 3 times you have 3 identical event listeners that respond to J or D leading to the observed triple input. They will be called in the order they've been connected.

If you no longer need an event handler disconnect it. This could be done using the InputEnded event. If G is released disconnect the listeners that handle U and J.

Alternatively to adding a new listener you can also use a variable that stores the information that G is being pressed.

Simple, untested example:

```
local pressedKeys = {}

local function = OnInputBegan(input)
  pressedKeys[input.KeyCode] = true

  if pressedKeys[Enum.KeyCode.G] and pressedKeys[Enum.KeyCode.U] then
    print("G and U are down!")
  end
end

local function OnInputEnded(input)
  pressedKeys[input.KeyCode] = nil
end
local userInput = game:GetService("UserInputService")    
userInput.InputBegan:Connect(OnInputBegan)
userInput.InputEnded:Connect(OnInputEnded)
```